# Clip two Shape with Mapwingis : Resulting shapefile has no shapes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, dictionary, shapes, shapefile

I use MapWingis.ocx for my code

I use MapWingis.Shapefile for declare an "Shapefile" object

I just wanna to Clip two shapefile. There is an API function format :

```
Shapefile.Clip (bool SelectedOnlySubject, Shapefile sfOverlay, bool SelectedOnlyOverlay)
```

I start to write this.

```
    Dim sfOverlay As New MapWinGIS.Shapefile
    Dim sfinput As New MapWinGIS.Shapefile
    Dim sfClip As New MapWinGIS.Shapefile
    Dim index1 As Integer
    Dim index2 As Integer

        index1 = CbBInputLayer.SelectedIndex
        index2 = CbBOverlayClipLayer.SelectedIndex
        sfinput = FormMain.AxMapMain.get_Shapefile(index1)
        sfOverlay = FormMain.AxMapMain.get_Shapefile(index2)

    sfClip = sfinput.Clip(False, sfOverlay, False)
        If sfClip Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to calculate Clip :" + sfinput.ErrorMsg(sfinput.LastErrorCode))
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to calculate Clip :" + sfOverlay.ErrorMsg(sfOverlay.LastErrorCode))
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to calculate Clip :" + sfClip.ErrorMsg(sfClip.LastErrorCode))

        Else
            shape2.Add(sfClip)
        End If
```

the results `is Nothing`and

`sfInput` give *Resulting shapefile has no shapes*

`sfOverlay` give *No Error*

`sfClip` give *Null Reference set to an instance of an object*

how I can fix this? Is there any mistake?

Comment: Have you tried `Catfood` from [`CodePlex`](https://shapefile.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: i will try it, is it for change the declaration of `sfInput` , `sfOverlay` , and `sfClip` from Mapwingis.shapefile? @OneFineDay

Comment: It is an `SDK` for opening and accessing shape file elements. I use it to read polygons and then plot them on a map. It does more...

Answer (score 0):

this code is no mistake. my mistake is the maps that I use to input and clip it. Thanks for comments